# Issue while installing a language pack : this file already exists

Tags: magento, server

I tried to install a spanish language pack through magento connect. It seems it was already installed since in the magento connect screen I got a message saying something like : "error : this file is already installed". Since then the server is down.

How can I fix this ? I haven't written down the path to the exact file that seems to cause this issue, and I can't find it.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you receive any errors as to why the site is down?

Comment: When I try to connect to my store, this message shows : Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why your server is down: check the magento directory for a maintenance flag file and delete it.  It probably was set, but since it got an error it wasn't removed.